# Can someone correct this Excel 2010 Macro?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, macros

Well, I recorded a macro but it is not working correctly. It is as followed:

```
Sub OpenCase1()
'
' OpenCase1 Macro
'

'
    Range("G5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-4]C[-3]"
    Range("G5").Select
End Sub
```

It's a simple command, I thought, but obviously it is not working. 
What I want it to do is, when clicking the macro, it will change cell G5 to =D1, copying the contents of cell D1. From previous help I have gotten, the `Select` parts in the macro may be a problem, however it might not be the case in this.

All help is rather appreciated, please help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplify the code by accessing the cell directly without `Select`

```
Range("G5").Value = "=D1"
```

or

```
Range("G5").Formula = "=D1"
```

or if you want to use your notation for some other reason

```
Range("G5").FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-4]C[-3]"
```

Comment: Heh Heh, or I could have done that. Thank you Amer. :)